# Apple Message Filter Extension with Flutter not working

Tags: ios, flutter, sms

I'm trying to use iOS native extensions in my flutter bloc. It's message filter extension specifically. I implemented this extension on XCode with this route > New > Target > This extension. I read this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_mms_message_filtering). According to this document and answers I've read which is related to this issue, there's no extra configuration.
Here is my code snippet of extension:

```
 func handle(_ queryRequest: ILMessageFilterQueryRequest, context: ILMessageFilterExtensionContext, completion: @escaping (ILMessageFilterQueryResponse) -> Void) {
    // First, check whether to filter using offline data (if possible).
    print(">>>>> HANDLED SMS")
    let offlineAction = self.offlineAction(for: queryRequest)

    switch offlineAction {
    case .allow, .junk, .promotion, .transaction:
        // Based on offline data, we know this message should either be Allowed, Filtered as Junk, Promotional or Transactional. Send response immediately.
        let response = ILMessageFilterQueryResponse()
        response.action = offlineAction

        completion(response)

    case .none:
        // Based on offline data, we do not know whether this message should be Allowed or Filtered. Defer to network.
        // Note: Deferring requests to network requires the extension target's Info.plist to contain a key with a URL to use. See documentation for details.
        context.deferQueryRequestToNetwork() { (networkResponse, error) in
            let response = ILMessageFilterQueryResponse()
            response.action = .none

            if let networkResponse = networkResponse {
                // If we received a network response, parse it to determine an action to return in our response.
                response.action = self.action(for: networkResponse)
            } else {
                NSLog("Error deferring query request to network: \(String(describing: error))")
            }

            completion(response)
        }

    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}

private func offlineAction(for queryRequest: ILMessageFilterQueryRequest) -> ILMessageFilterAction {
    // Replace with logic to perform offline check whether to filter first (if possible).
    print("IOS MESSAGE EXTENSIONNNN!!!")
    return .none
}

private func action(for networkResponse: ILNetworkResponse) -> ILMessageFilterAction {
    // Replace with logic to parse the HTTP response and data payload of `networkResponse` to return an action.
    return .none
}
```

I also activated my app via messages > unknown & spam. I expected a log message when my phone received an sms bu there is no log message. What I'm missing? Do I need extra configuration for flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not actually from the flutter background but from my experience in native iOS, after activating your app via messages > unknown & spam, you need to **run your message filter extension from Xcode in iPhone's messages app**.

For more detail explanation please refer to my answer
[Detail explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76161226/21803134)